# How to refer environment varibales in MySQL configuration file

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to use environment variables in `my.cnf`?
Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
[client]
user = $MYSQL_USER
password = $MYSQL_PASSWORD
host = db
```

But, with the configuration above, when I try to connect to MySQL, I get

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '$MYSQL_USER'@'188.1.1.5'
> (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. MySQL does not support variables in the configuration file.

If you want to ease deployment you should look into configuration management.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

See `mysql_config_editor` as a convenient way to both establish your credentials and make them reasonably secure.

Since it is a one-time setup, you don't even need the $variables after that.